# kubeflow OutputPath/InputPath question when writing/reading multiple files

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I've a data-fetch stage where I get multiple DFs and serialize those. I'm currently treating OutputPath as directory - create it if it doesn't exist etc. and then serialize all the DFs in that path with different names for each DF.

In a subsequent pipeline stage (say, predict) I need to retrieve all those through InputPath.

Now, from the documentation it seems InputPath/OutputPath as file. Does kubeflow as any limitation if I use it as directory?

Answer (score 1):

The ComponentSpec's `{inputPath: input_name}` and `{outputPath: output_name}` placeholders and their Python analogs (`input_name: InputPath()`/`output_name: OutputPath()`) are designed to support both files/blobs and directories.

They are expected to provide the path for the input/output data. No matter whether the data is a blob/file or a directory.

The only limitation is that UX might not be able to preview such artifacts.
But the pipeline itself would work.

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented with a trivial pipeline - no issue is observed if InputPath/OutputPath is used as directory.